# $\kappa <\operatorname{cf}(2^\kappa)$ without König's inequality

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

How can I prove $\kappa<\operatorname{cf}(2^\kappa)$ inequality without using König's inequality?
We got this as a practice exercise, but I don't know how to approach this without König.
Any hint would be awesome!

I tried it with different other Corollaries which I found in Jech, but nothing worth to post it here.

Comment: Would it count to simply give the proof of König's theorem adapted to this special case?

Comment: No, you know that's cheating :).

Comment: No.. I think that is not allowed ;) Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from $\kappa \lt \kappa^{cf(\kappa)}$ that can be proved without Konig's theorem (see e.g. Jech/Set Theory Theorem 3.11).

Now to get the requested equality substitute $2^\kappa$ instead of $\kappa$ and use the fact that $\kappa \le cf(2^\kappa)$ (that can be seen by assuming the opposite, and getting a contradiction from $2^{k * cf(2^\kappa)} \lt 2^{\kappa * \kappa}$).

Comment: $\kappa<\kappa^{\rm{cf}(\kappa)}$ is what most people would call König's theorem. Its proof is just the general argument with many parameters coinciding, anyway, which is *not* the kind of argument Luca is asking for.

Comment: Then maybe this exercise was taken from Jech, as he explicitly says that the proof of theorem 3.11 does not rely on Konig's theorem.

Comment: The question is not out of the book I think. Our professor gave it as a practice for the exam. Well, in the proof in 3.11 in Jech it's like Eran sais. The König inequality comes in Chapter 5. There he sais it can be obtained from König. But in the proof in 3.11 he didn't use König. So maybe it would be fine?